# Validations not working in REST API with Spring 2.5.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I'm trying to add validations to my DTOs in Spring `2.5.1`, i've added spring-boot-starter-validation to `pom.xml` file, i've tried `@NotEmpty @Min @Max @Pattern` but no annotation is working

**DTO :**

```
public class SiteDTO {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String code;


    @Min(value = 1, message = "Vlan ID : Minimum 1.")
    @Max(value = 9999, message = "Vlan ID : Maximum 4096")
    private String vlanId;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^((0|1\\d?\\d?|2[0-4]?\\d?|25[0-5]?|[3-9]\\d?)\\.){3}(0|1\\d?\\d?|2[0-4]?\\d?|25[0-5]?|[3-9]\\d?)$", message = "Incorrect IP format.")
    private String ipAddress;

}
```

I also made sure to annotate the api with @Validated and annotate the passed dto with @Valid :

```
    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateSite(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody SiteDTO siteDTO) {
            
        try {
            siteService.saveSite(siteDTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }       
    }
```

**Validation handler :**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) ->{

            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String message = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, message);
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**POM.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myapp-api</name>
    <description>my app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myapp-api</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can you pls share your complete pom.xml? Because above code is working fine for me

Comment: i've shared the pom

Answer (score 1):

One observation is, Getter/Setter methods need to be added for SiteDTO pojo class. I tried with below code and the validation works as expected.

**Maven POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.so</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSpringBootValidation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Main Class:**

```
package com.so;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SOValidationApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting TestSpringBootApplication..");
        SpringApplication.run(SOValidationApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Pojo Class**

```
package com.so.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class SiteDTO {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String code;


    @Min(value = 1, message = "Vlan ID : Minimum 1.")
    @Max(value = 9999, message = "Vlan ID : Maximum 4096")
    private String vlanId;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^((0|1\\d?\\d?|2[0-4]?\\d?|25[0-5]?|[3-9]\\d?)\\.){3}(0|1\\d?\\d?|2[0-4]?\\d?|25[0-5]?|[3-9]\\d?)$", message = "Incorrect IP format.")
    private String ipAddress;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getVlanId() {
        return vlanId;
    }

    public void setVlanId(String vlanId) {
        this.vlanId = vlanId;
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SiteDTO{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", code='" + code + '\'' +
                ", vlanId='" + vlanId + '\'' +
                ", ipAddress='" + ipAddress + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.so.controller;

import com.so.model.SiteDTO;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
public class SOController {
    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateSite(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody SiteDTO siteDTO) {
        System.out.println("### Input Object ID: " + id);
        try {
            System.out.println("### Site DTO: " + siteDTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

**Exception Handler:**

```
package com.so.errorhandler;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        System.out.println("### Exception Handler..");
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) ->{

            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String message = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, message);
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working, i have getters/setters just didn't put them in the question